# IndexOutOfBoundsException when indexing with value from Collections.min

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to get the index of the min value but I am getting this error when the min the first element is 570 (index = 0). What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
//ArrayList of distanceList [570, 621, 716, 906, 1055, 1253, 1314, 1314]
ArrayList<Integer> distanceList = entry.getValue();
//min is 570
int min = Collections.min(distanceList);
int index = distanceList.get(min);
```

Error:

```
threw exception [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 570, Size: 8] with root cause
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 570, Size: 8
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with  `int index = distanceList.get(min);` you geht the `min`-th element of `distanceList`.

try `int index = distanceList.indexOf(min);` instead

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.ArrayList.get(int index)` method returns the element at the specified position in this list.

**Declaration**

Following is the declaration for java.util.ArrayList.get() method

```
public E get(int index)
```

**Parameters**

index -- The index of the element to return.

**Exception**

IndexOutOfBoundsException -- if the index is out of range.

---

```
  int min = Collections.min(distanceList);//this returns 570
  int index = distanceList.get(min);//you are passing 570 as index where array
```

size is 8 which means its index is 7. So causes the exception

Answer (score 1):

This type of error occurs because you try to access an array position that is not exists.the initial position index is 0 (570 is value) and the last member has size-1 value.
Then, in your case, you can access position using indexes from 0 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

You are using value stored in array list as index. It's wrong. Index is the position where the element is stored ( here integer value)

Use distancelist.indexOf(min)